# Is $\mathop{\mathrm{arccsc}}(\csc x)=0$ for $x$ integer multiples of $\pi$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

We know that $\csc x$ is not defined at integer multiples of $\pi$. Then, is it generally true that

$$\mathrm{arccsc} \,(\csc x)=0,$$

for integer multiples of $\pi$?

Comment: $\csc x$ is not defined at integer multiples of $\pi$, so the composition is undefined at those points. It is not equal to $0$; it is not equal to **anything**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. Can we say that the limit of this function at $x$ integer multiples of $\pi$ tends to zero? I am surprised why Mathematica gives $arccsc[\csc \pi]]=0$ without any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not valid for integer multiples of $\pi$ because both functions are undefined at those points.

$$\csc^{-1}\space y =0 \longrightarrow \text{FALSE}$$ so there is no solution to $\quad\csc^{-1}(\csc x)=0$

Comment: Can we say that the limit of this function at $x$ integer multiples of $\pi$ tends to zero? I am surprised why Mathematica gives $arccsc[\csc \pi]]=0$ without any warnings. @petasis

Comment: @Martha97. You are right. Smehow, late at nigh I misread as x-0